# Cubic spline interpolation of Python ndarray

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, interpolation, spline

I have a 4 dimensional array of data of shape `A = (X, Y, Z, Q)` and I'd like to interpolate to position `(x, y, z)` for each value of `Q`, i.e. end up with an array of length `Q`.

I've been using `scipy.interpolate.RegularGridInterpolator` to do this on a `q`-by-`q` basis like so:

```
Q = np.zeros(A.shape[-1])
for q in range(len(Q)):
    interp_f = RegularGridInterpolator([X,Y,Z], A[:,:,:,q])
    v, = interp_f(np.array([x,y,z]))
    Q[q] = v
```

And this works fine but it takes about 2 minutes to run since my typical dimensions of `A` are `(10, 10, 3, 25000)`.

Is there a (much) faster way of doing this?

I'd REALLY like to do a cubic spline interpolation in 3D instead of linear interpolation but can't find any resource for 3+ dimensional data.

Thanks!

Comment: This post has a pretty good answer to your question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32753449/what-to-do-if-i-want-3d-spline-smooth-interpolation-of-random-unstructured-data

Comment: Yes, I looked at Rbf() but it requires that all axes be the same length. I am dealing with regular gridded data but the shape is not symmetric. Or did I misunderstand how to use Rbf? Thanks @jakevdp !